# How to use UTF-16 in URL encoding?

Tags: java, url, encoding

Currently I am using utf-8 for URL encoding. I want to convert it to UTF-16.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When encoding Unicode characters in URLs, it's necessary to encode them in such a fashion that all URL parsers and consumers can understand your URLs.

To that end; when the URL was expanded by RFCs in the wake of the development of Unicode and related standards and tools, it was decided that the encoding to employ for encoding characters (using percent escapes) was to be UTF-8, as this would mean that established ASCII escapes would Just Work™.

Consequently, even if you could generate URLs with UTF-16-based percent escapes, no other program would be able to understand them, making them useless. In fact, by matter of definition, they wouldn't even *be* URLs.

There's also the question of why on earth you would want to use UTF-16 for *anything*, it being silly and all.

Remember: **Never Don't Use UTF-8!** (*N'DUUH!*)

Answer (score 1):

URL escapes, as in %nn hex values, encode bytes. 8-bit bytes. If for some very nonstandard reason you want to encode bytes of UTF-16 instead of UTF-8, you must first pick a byte order (BE or LE). Then you have to write code in your program to take the two bytes of each 16-bit UTF-16 character and represent it as %nn in hex.