# Unicode Chars in JWPlayer 6 RSS playlists (with demo)

Tags: unicode, rss, jwplayer

Ok, I have a cloudfront install which has characters such as ö and ó in the folder/file name.

JWPlayer goes into infinite buffering whenever I point an RTMP stream at it which has one of these.

What do I escape these to in order for this to work? It's driving me nuts. I've tried ditching RSS and using JSON but couldn't get that to work either.

Demo: http://apricot.viviotech.net/miscellaneous/index2.html

You'll see that N*E*R*D tracks work - so it's not the overall config/player, just anything with an unusual Char.

Help?

UPDATE:
Right, managed to get something working: if I copy and paste the o with diareses from the generated HTML and resave, it works. 
i.e apricot.viviotech.net/miscellaneous/index3.html

They look indentical, but in a hex editor, the one which DOESN'T work looks like BjÃ¶rk (with a byte encoding of C3 B6) And the one which DOES comes out as BjoÌˆrk (with a byte encoding of 6F CC 88) (purely in the underlyigng HEX). In the HTML source, they look identical, but obviously there's some encoding issue in the way these are being output which I just don't understand.

Comment: I would try to url encode those characters. I would use this tool to url encode them - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: Hmm, I have been looking into this. Maybe one of these will help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925875/how-to-use-utf-16-in-url-encoding
http://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/

Comment: @EthanLongTail
Right, managed to get something working: if I copy and paste the o with diareses from the generated HTML and resave, it works.

i.e http://apricot.viviotech.net/miscellaneous/index3.html

They look indentical, but in a hex editor, the one which DOESN'T work looks like BjÃ¶rk (with a byte encoding of C3 B6) And the one which DOES comes out as BjoÌˆrk (with a byte encoding of 6F CC 88) (purely in the underlyigng HEX. In the HTML source, they look identical, but obviously there's some encoding issue in the way these are being output which I just don't understand.

Comment: That is strange. On the first one, the two (ö ö) look different. If I view the source of your page in Firefox and search for the rtmp server url, I can't find the a match with the 2nd one. It breaks on the different "o" symbols. I hope that helps with a clue, but it looks like even FF see's a slight difference between these two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16477559/442412 : note to self, concentrate more on what's going in rather than what's going out...